# Why aren't static methods on my models available in the Google Cloud Endpoints client libraries?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-endpoints

I have the following Entity as a return value for one of my endpoints.  When I generate the client libraries, it seems to ignore the static methods, which leaves Player.key() unavailable.  I can't find any documentation anywhere which explains what will be allowed or removed from the client libraries, so I'm trying to figure it out, but some framework for understanding other than trial and error would be helpful.

```
@Entity
public class Player {
  public static final String PLAYER = "Player";
  public static final String UUID = "uuid";
  public static final String NAME = "name";

  @Id
  String uuid;

  String name;

  public String getUuid() {
    return uuid;
  }

  public void setUuid(String uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public static Key key(String uuid) {
    return KeyFactory.createKey(PLAYER, uuid);
  }
}
```

If I rewrite the methods as follows it works:

```
  public Key key(String uuid) {
    return KeyFactory.createKey(PLAYER, uuid);
  }
```

But that requires me to do silly things like the following in my client code, which I'd like to avoid:

```
Key playerKey = new Player().key(uuid);
```

I apparently can't write this method in a separate class on the client side because I don't have access to the appengine SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated client libraries primarily serve to model your data, not to support auxiliary methods. You can include these utilities in another library if you need them. I'm not convinced the non-static version of the method is doing what you want on the client side, if the syntax works, because they client libraries don't copy entities or their dependencies.

Comment: What's the right way to share business logic between the client and the server?  A separate shared library?

It seems like the only methods that work are basic getters and setters, is that correct?  It seems like it's trying to preserve a privacy model, but I can't seem to use simple methods like hasX() { return X != null }.  Is the rules by which these methods are generated documented anywhere?

Is there a way to have the models that the server uses work the same way as the generated client libraries?

Comment: Yes, you should use a separate library. The client library generates getters/setters corresponding to the fields in a JSON schema. Therefore, if you don't mind having "hasX" as a field in your response, you can make it a property of your response using [@ApiResourceProperty](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/ApiResourceProperty.html).